# If $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt = 0$ on $[0,1],$ does $f(x) = 0 $ on $[0,1] ?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Given f: (0,1) $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb R$. f is a continuous function and improper integrable.

If $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt = 0$ $\forall x \in [0,1] $,

Does $f(x) = 0 $ $\forall x \in [0,1] $ ?

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus ?

Comment: On a technical note, the answer is "no", since $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are undefined.  If you instead ask whether $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, then the answer is "yes," by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: On a side note: without the assumption that $f$ is continuous, and assuming only that $f$ is $L^1$, the Lebesgue differentiation theorem would still imply that $f(x) = 0$ for almost every $x \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  Indeed.  So the super advanced solution of this elementary problem would be: (i) $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$ at every Lebesgue point of $f$.  (ii) But every point of continuity is a Lebesgue point of $f$.  On the other hand:  the Lebesgue integral does not include the improper Riemann integral so the super advanced solution doesn't actually solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Can we appeal to the Fundamental Theorem of the Calculus?**

Certainly ... if you can find one in your textbook for *improper integrals*.  Many textbooks make no such statement, assuming that you can use the regular version as needed.

If you cannot find one, then prove a simple one by basing the proof on the usual Fundamental theorem.

**THEOREM**. Suppose that $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ and that $f$ is  integrable in the improper Riemann sense  on  $ (a,b)$.  Then,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$$
at every point $x\in (a,b)$ at which $f$ is continous.

Proof.  If $a<x_0<x<b$ then
$$ \int_{a}^x f(t)\,dt  = \int_a^{x_0} f(t)\,dt +  \int_{x_0}^x f(t)\,dt  $$
where the first integral on the right is improper Riemann and the second is ordinary Riemann. By the usual FTC, since $f$ is Riemann integrable here,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x_0}^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$$
at every point $x\in (a,b)$ at which $f$ is continous. Etc.

**Comment**.  Is this pedantic?  Of course. But a theorem proved for the Riemann integral is not *automatically* true for the improper Riemann integral. One checks!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, using the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that $F(x)-F(0)=0$ where $F'(x)=f(x)$. Hence $F(x)=F(0)$ for all $x$, which means $F(x)$ is a constant function, and hence $f(x)=F'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a $z \in (0,1)$ with

$f(z) >0$ (or $f(z)<0$).

Since f is continuos there is
a

$e>0$ s.t. for $z-e <x<z+e$

we have $f(x)>0$.

Then

$I:=\int_{z-e}^{z+e}f(x)dx \not =0;$

But

$I=$

$\int_{0}^{z+e}f(x)dx - \int_{0}^{z-e}f(x)dx=0$,

a contradiction.

Comment: A simplification makes this a bit more elementary.  Argue that on $[z-e,z+e]\subset (a,b)$ we can have  $f(x) \geq \frac12f(z)=c>0$.  Then $\int_{z-e}^{z+e}f(x)\,dx \geq 2ec>0$.  Same argument, but assumes less knowledge.